# split dataframe by row number in R

Tags: r, split

This is probably really simple, but I can't find a solution:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))

v <- c(3, 7)
```

is there an elegant way to split this dataframe in three elements (of a list) at the row number specified in v?

Comment: Where should rows 3 and 7 go?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that rows `1&2` goes in the first split, `3,4,5,6` in the second and `7 to nrow(df)` goes in the last

```
 split(df, cumsum(1:nrow(df) %in% v))
```

but if `1:3` rows are in the first split, then comes `4:7`, and in the third `8 to nrow(df)`

```
  split(df, cumsum(c(TRUE,(1:nrow(df) %in% v)[-nrow(df)])) )
```

Or as @James mentioned in the comments,

```
  split(df, cumsum(1:nrow(df) %in% (v+1)))
```

Comment: It's probably easier just to do `(v+1)` for the second interpretation.

Answer (score 7):

Another way:

```
split(df, findInterval(1:nrow(df), v))
```

For the alternative interpretation, you can use:

```
split(df, cut(1:nrow(df), unique(c(1, v, nrow(df))), include.lowest=TRUE))
```