# R: split concatenated dataframe by row

Tags: r

I have a big text file that is the result of another program appending multiple tables together (including headers). I'd like to read that file into R and split it apart.

This is sort of similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132290/split-dataframe-by-row-number-in-r), except I don't know the row number, and I need to split it on the header row, not a particular row number. I do know that each table starts with a header, though, and that the Wvlgth values always start with 337.0 and end with 823.0.

Here is the text file. It looks identical to this, except with 550 rows.

```
Wvlgth Global
337.0  .4345
337.5  .1256
338.0  .8754
<...>
821.0  .9923
822.0  .7124
823.0  .2999
Wvlgth Global
337.0  .5632
337.5  .1245
338.0  .0012
<...>
821.0  .1987
822.0  .6743
823.0  .2045
```

Here is the code to generate something similar in R:

```
    df = data.frame("Wvlgth" = c('337.0','337.5','338.0','821.0','822.0','823.0'), 
                   "Global" = c(.4345, .1256, .8754, .9923, .7124, .2999))
```

I want this to turn into multiple dataframes, like so:

#### Dataframe 1

```
     Wvlgth Global
1    337.0 .4345
2    337.5 .1256
3    338.0 .8754
<...>
548  821.0 .9923
549  822.0 .7124
550  823.0 .2999
```

#### Dataframe 2

```
     Wvlgth Global
1    337.0 .5632
2    337.5 .1245
3    338.0 .0012
<...>
548  821.0 .1987
549  822.0 .6743
550  823.0 .2045
```

Not sure if there is a way to do this through read.csv or if i need to read the whole thing in and split it after the fact.

Comment: There's not a way to do it on import that I've seen. You can either fix the file (in R with `readLines` or with system tools) or fix the data.frame manually afterwards by subsetting with `df[!grepl('\\D', df$Wvlgnth), ]` and applying `type.convert` manually.

Comment: I would import it `as.numeric` and then split it using `NA`, `NA` as flag for the rows

Comment: @agerom I don't think I understand what you're saying, sorry...How would using the NA rows as a flag for splitting the dataframe be any different than using a row of strings?

Comment: @ale19 would you mind sharing a portion of the csv?

Comment: @agerom Is the portion from my original post not enough?

Comment: @ale19 I imagine that <...> contains only numeric data, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do that using `split` from `data.table`. Basically, you need to create a group column using `cumsum` on "Wvlgth" in column 1. Then you can split the result into a list. You can then access the elements of that list like so: `df_list[[1]]`

```
df <- read.table(text="Wvlgth Global
337.0  .4345
                337.5  .1256
                338.0  .8754
                821.0  .9923
                822.0  .7124
                823.0  .2999
                Wvlgth Global
                337.0  .5632
                337.5  .1245
                338.0  .0012
                821.0  .1987
                822.0  .6743
                823.0  .2045",header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$group <- cumsum(df[,1]=="Wvlgth")
df_list <- split(df, list(df$group))

$`1`
      V1     V2 group
1 Wvlgth Global     1
2  337.0  .4345     1
3  337.5  .1256     1
4  338.0  .8754     1
5  821.0  .9923     1
6  822.0  .7124     1
7  823.0  .2999     1

$`2`
       V1     V2 group
8  Wvlgth Global     2
9   337.0  .5632     2
10  337.5  .1245     2
11  338.0  .0012     2
12  821.0  .1987     2
13  822.0  .6743     2
14  823.0  .2045     2
```

To access a single data.frame:

```
df_list[[1]]
      V1     V2 group
1 Wvlgth Global     1
2  337.0  .4345     1
3  337.5  .1256     1
4  338.0  .8754     1
5  821.0  .9923     1
6  822.0  .7124     1
7  823.0  .2999     1
```

Additionally, if you want to set up the column names of the data.frames, you can use `lapply`:

```
new_col_name <- c("Wvlgth", "Global","group")
df_list <- lapply(df_list, setNames, nm = new_col_name) #set names
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) x[-1,]) #remove first row

> df_list
$`1`
  Wvlgth Global group
2  337.0  .4345     1
3  337.5  .1256     1
4  338.0  .8754     1
5  821.0  .9923     1
6  822.0  .7124     1
7  823.0  .2999     1

$`2`
   Wvlgth Global group
9   337.0  .5632     2
10  337.5  .1245     2
11  338.0  .0012     2
12  821.0  .1987     2
13  822.0  .6743     2
14  823.0  .2045     2
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. If it's not too much to ask, why need to split the result into a list? I get an error when I run that line of code without `list()`, but I don't understand what that error means, even after some Googling.

Comment: @ale19 If you are referring to `list` in `split(df, list(df$group))`, it's just the way `data.table` uses inputs. On a broader note, it is good practice in this case to store the data.frames into a list. As you can see, it's easy to do operations on all data.frames using lapply. If you need to get back the results into a single data.frame, you can use rbindlist from data.table.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! It's the same thing in pandas when you are concatenating a dataframe, but I didn't realize that. Still learning all the syntax in R. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I created some monte carlo [data](https://ufile.io/p9qe3) myself

```
#loading libraries
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)

input <- readLines("path/to/your/csv",warn = F)#reading input csv file
input <- trimws(input)#removing spaces left and right
```

Looking like:

```
 >input
 [1] "Wvlgth Global" "337.0 0.4345"  "337.5 0.1256"  "338.0 0.8754"  "821.0 0.9923"  "822.0 0.7124"  "823.0 0.2999"  "Wvlgth Global" "327.0 0.5345"  "317.5 0.5256" 
[11] "358.0 0.4754"  "871.0 0.93235" "882.0 0.2124"  "893.0 0.1999"  "811.0 0.93235" "972.0 0.33235" "Wvlgth Global" "893.0 0.2399"  "193.0 0.5120"  "892.0 0.3199"
```

In order to transform it to a more useful format (data.table):

```
dt<-data.table(ldply(stri_split(str = input,fixed=" "),"["))#creating data.table
dt[,Wvlgth:=as.numeric(V1)][,Global:=as.numeric(V2)][,V1:=NULL][,V2:=NULL]#performing some column manipulation (by importing as.numeric, the characters are transformed into NA's
dt[,containsNA:=is.na(Wvlgth)]#adding boolean tag if Wvlgth is NA
```

The resulting data table looks like:

```
>dt
     Wvlgth  Global containsNA
1:     NA      NA       TRUE
2:  337.0 0.43450      FALSE
3:  337.5 0.12560      FALSE
4:  338.0 0.87540      FALSE
5:  821.0 0.99230      FALSE
6:  822.0 0.71240      FALSE
7:  823.0 0.29990      FALSE
8:     NA      NA       TRUE
9:  327.0 0.53450      FALSE
10:  317.5 0.52560      FALSE
11:  358.0 0.47540      FALSE
12:  871.0 0.93235      FALSE
13:  882.0 0.21240      FALSE
14:  893.0 0.19990      FALSE
15:  811.0 0.93235      FALSE
16:  972.0 0.33235      FALSE
17:     NA      NA       TRUE
18:  893.0 0.23990      FALSE
19:  193.0 0.51200      FALSE
20:  892.0 0.31990      FALSE
```

We then apply

```
 l1<-split(dt,cumsum(dt$containsNA))
```

yielding in:

```
>l1
$`1`
  Wvlgth Global containsNA
1     NA     NA       TRUE
2  337.0 0.4345      FALSE
3  337.5 0.1256      FALSE
4  338.0 0.8754      FALSE
5  821.0 0.9923      FALSE
6  822.0 0.7124      FALSE
7  823.0 0.2999      FALSE

$`2`
   Wvlgth  Global containsNA
8      NA      NA       TRUE
9   327.0 0.53450      FALSE
10  317.5 0.52560      FALSE
11  358.0 0.47540      FALSE
12  871.0 0.93235      FALSE
13  882.0 0.21240      FALSE 
14  893.0 0.19990      FALSE
15  811.0 0.93235      FALSE
16  972.0 0.33235      FALSE

$`3`
  Wvlgth Global containsNA
17     NA     NA       TRUE
18    893 0.2399      FALSE
19    193 0.5120      FALSE
20    892 0.3199      FALSE
```

Finally in order to acquire the format we desire (removing NA rows and `containsNA` column that is) we perform on every element of the list the following operation:

```
lapply(l1,function(x) x[,.SD[(!is.na(Wvlgth))]][,containsNA:=NULL])
```

resulting in:

```
$`1`
   Wvlgth Global
1:  337.0 0.4345 
2:  337.5 0.1256
3:  338.0 0.8754
4:  821.0 0.9923
5:  822.0 0.7124
6:  823.0 0.2999

$`2`
    Wvlgth  Global
1:  327.0 0.53450
2:  317.5 0.52560
3:  358.0 0.47540
4:  871.0 0.93235
5:  882.0 0.21240
6:  893.0 0.19990
7:  811.0 0.93235
8:  972.0 0.33235

$`3`
   Wvlgth Global
1:    893 0.2399
2:    193 0.5120
3:    892 0.3199
```

## ADDENDUM:

In case the link to the MC data gets deprecated, here is the `data` that was used for the particular question.

```
 Wvlgth Global
 337.0 0.4345
 337.5 0.1256
 338.0 0.8754
 821.0 0.9923
 822.0 0.7124
 823.0 0.2999
 Wvlgth Global
 327.0 0.5345
 317.5 0.5256
 358.0 0.4754
 871.0 0.93235
 882.0 0.2124
 893.0 0.1999
 811.0 0.93235
 972.0 0.33235
 Wvlgth Global
 893.0 0.2399
 193.0 0.5120
 892.0 0.3199
```