# Concatenate alternate characters from different columns in R programming

Tags: r, concatenation

I have a df with 2 columns. I need to combine Col1 and Col2 in Col3 - alternate text separated by ">" a1-b1;a2-b2;a3-b3;...

Example

```
|      Col1       |           Col2   |            Col3              |

| abcd > de > efg | ppppp > ppt > pp | abcd-ppppp > de-ppt > efg-pp | 

| hij > kl > iiii | aaa > bbb > hhh  | hij-aaa > kl-bbb > iiii-hhh  | 

| aa              | fff              | aa-fff                       | 

| a > bbb         |  pp > a          | a-pp > bbb-a                 |
```

....

How can I do that in R programming?
Thanks

Comment: you should share some usable example data by doing `dput` on the object you're working with

Comment: Have you tried anything? Seems like a combination of `strsplit` and `paste` should cut it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a pain in the ass to solve. In the future, for our sanity please consider how you output your data. This could have been easily solved if, however the data was generated, you consider downstream analysis. Anyway enough whinging here is the solution.

Lets generate your data:

```
Col1 <- c("abcd > de > efg", "hij > kl > iiii", "aa", "a > bbb")
Col2 <- c("ppppp > ppt > pp", "aaa > bbb > hhh", "fff", "pp > a")
dat <- data.frame(Col1, Col2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Next using `apply` we strip, separate and flatten `Col1` and `Col2` and add the first separator `-`:

```
l1 <- apply(dat, 2, function(x) trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, split = ">"))))
l2 <- apply(l1, 1, function(x) paste0(x[1], "-", x[2]))
```

The next part was surprisingly difficult, after much googling I found a solution (a hack) to split a list of characters by a numeric vector.

```
#thanks: https://techoverflow.net/2012/11/10/r-count-occurrences-of-character-in-string/
#gets occurrences of ">" for later use
countCharOccurrences <- function(char, s) {
  s2 <- gsub(char,"",s)
  return (nchar(s) - nchar(s2))
}

o <- countCharOccurrences(">", dat$Col1)+1
df <- as.data.frame(l2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Split `df` by the occurrences of ">" (i.e the values of `o`):

```
# Thanks to this SO answer:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132290/split-dataframe-by-row-number-in-r
l2a <- split(df, cumsum(c(TRUE,(1:nrow(df) %in% cumsum(o))[-nrow(df)])))
```

Finally, we collapse list of dataframes and add the final separator `>`:

```
l3 <- lapply(l2a, function(x) paste(x[,1], collapse = " > "))
```

Then combine with your starting dataframe:

```
dat$Col3 <- l3

             Col1             Col2                         Col3
1 abcd > de > efg ppppp > ppt > pp abcd-ppppp > de-ppt > efg-pp
2 hij > kl > iiii  aaa > bbb > hhh  hij-aaa > kl-bbb > iiii-hhh
3              aa              fff                       aa-fff
4         a > bbb           pp > a                 a-pp > bbb-a
```

Tada!

edit: I had forgotten `l3` is a list of objects. You need to use `unlist` to flatten them like this:

```
dat$Col3 <- unlist(l3)
```